# SQL to get unique rows in Netezza DB

Tags: sql, select, greatest-n-per-group, netezza

I have a table with rows like:

```
id    group_name_code  
1     999  
2     16  
3     789  
4     999  
5     231  
6     999  
7     349  
8     16  
9     819  
10     999  
11     654
```

But I want output rows like this:

```
id    group_name_code
1     999  
2     16  
3     789  
4     231  
5     349  
6     819  
7     654
```

Will this query help?

```
select id, distinct(group_name_code) from group_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

*Distinct values for `group_name_code` and a sequential `id` ordered by minimum id per set of `group_name_code`.*

Netezza has the `DISTINCT` key word, but not [`DISTINCT ON ()` (Postgres feature)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860):
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_select.html

You could:

```
SELECT DISTINCT group_name_code FROM group_table;
```

No parentheses, the `DISTINCT` key word does not require parentheses.
But you would not get the sequential `id` you show with this.

There are "analytic functions" a.k.a. window functions:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/c_dbuser_overview_analytic_funcs.html

And there is also `row_number()`:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_functions.html

So this should work:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY min(id)) AS new_id, group_name_code
FROM   group_table
GROUP  BY group_name_code
ORDER  BY min(id);
```

Or use a subquery if Netezza should not allow to nest aggregate and window functions:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS new_id, group_name_code
FROM  (
   SELECT min(id) AS id, group_name_code
   FROM   group_table
   GROUP  BY group_name_code
   ) sub
ORDER  BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind losing data on `id` you can use an aggregate function on that column and group by `group_name_code`:

```
select min(id) as id, group_name_code 
from group_table
group by group_name_code
order by id;
```

This way you pull unique values for `group_name_code` and the lowest `id` for each code.

If you don't need id in your output (it seems like this doesn't correspond to input table) and just want the unique codes, try this:

```
select group_name_code 
from p
group by group_name_code
order by id;
```

This gets the codes you want.  If you want id to be the rownumber that will depend on which RDBMS you are using

Comment: This would not solve his problem. By the output, it is reordering the IDs, although I think that your proposal is probably what he really needs.

Comment: agreed, it looks like id in his sample output is like a rownumber, the relationship betwen id and code is lost.  I think honestly this is what is needed

Comment: thank you. i don't bother about losing  ID.i don't want to repeat group_name_code

Answer (score 0):

you can get that result using CTE, replace #t with you table name and value with group_name_code

; WITH tbl AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT **value** FROM **#t** 
)

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY **value**) AS id,*  FROM tbl

Comment: my apology, I am not sure If Netezza DB supports CTE or not.