# Select all columns from rows distinct on one column

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, netezza

I am using Netezza (based on PostgreSQL) and need to select all columns in a table for rows distinct on one column. A related question with answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913969/postgres-distinct-but-only-for-one-column), but it doesn't handle the case with all columns, going by that answer throws an error:

```
select distinct on (some_field) table1.* from table1 order by some_field;
```

Snippet from error with real data:

> "(" (at char 77) expecting '')''

Comment: What error are you getting?  The code might not do what you want but it shouldn't generate an error.

Comment: Can you add some sample table data and the expected result? (As well formatted text.)

Comment: How and where are you running that statement?

Comment: In fact I should have been clearer on this. I'm running this against Netezza which is based on PostgreSql

Comment: I removed the `postgresql` tag as Netezza is sufficiently different to Postgres.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your code should throw an error in Postgres.  However, it won't do what you expect without an `order by`:

```
select distinct on (some_field) table1.*
from table1
order by some_field;
```

Comment: That's misleading. `ORDER BY` is in now way necessary here.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter . . . Is that really true?  I know it might seem to work without the `ORDER BY`, but when I read the documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT), I have always interpreted it that the `ORDER BY` is needed not only for ordering within a group but to define the groups.  In particular, "The DISTINCT ON expression(s) must match the leftmost ORDER BY expression(s). "

Comment: Yes, that's really true. Leading `DISTINCT ON` and `ORDER BY` expressions must match - ***if*** both clauses are added. Groups for the distinct operation are defined by `DISTINCT ON` items *exclusively*. `ORDER BY` only affects the sort order of the result - and which rows are picked per group if more expressions are added to influence the order within groups.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter . . . Thank you for the clarification.  The documentation (which is generally very good for Postgres) could be clearer on this point -- by pointing out that `ORDER BY` is optional.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of your query is correct for ***Postgres*** (like you declared at first). See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

You later clarified you actually work with ***Netezza***, which is only loosely related to Postgres. [Wikipedia states:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netezza)

> Netezza is based on PostgreSQL 7.2, but does not maintain compatibility.

[Netezza does not seem to support `DISTINCT ON ()`, only `DISTINCT`.](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/psfa/7.2.1?topic=reference-select-retrieve-rows)
[It supports `row_number()`, though.](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/psfa/7.2.1?topic=reference-functions) So this works:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY some_field) AS rn
   FROM   table1
   ) sub
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

If, from each set with identical `some_field`, *any* row is good, you are done here. Else, implement your priority with `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause.

Related:

- [SQL to get unique rows in Netezza DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575643/sql-to-get-unique-rows-in-netezza-db/41910403#41910403)