# SELECT DISTINCT on one column, with multiple columns in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have to display result with select multiple column but distinct on only one column i have also used following queries and also refereed below link.

Query One.

```
select category , offer_id, store_image from  `tbl_coupan_offer` where
`offer_id` in (Select max(`offer_id`) FROM  `tbl_coupan_offer` group by `category`)
```

Above queries return all record with including duplicate

I want only display distinct category not repeated

Following is image

[image]

On image you can see Travel and Accessorises repeated

Second query

```
SELECT DISTINCT `category`,`offer_id`,`store_image` FROM `tbl_coupan_offer`
```

I also refereed this link [Select all columns from rows distinct on one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41894413/select-all-columns-from-rows-distinct-on-one-column)

Comment: what result do you expect?

Comment: I want to list of categories that will not repeated for e.g ( travel , accessories etc) but not repeated that i have mentioned in above image

Comment: So you want to exclude Travel and Accessories?

Comment: or include them with the largest ID?

Comment: I want like ( travel, accessorise, gift & flowers , hotel ... etc ) all categories but not repeated duplicate

Comment: Specify the expected result - as formatted text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Gordon said but as a subquery to get the appropriate image.

```
SELECT DISTINCT q.category, ch_offer_id, store_img
FROM
(
    SELECT category, MAX(offer_id) ch_offer_id
    FROM tbl_coupan_offer
    GROUP BY category
) q
JOIN tbl_coupan_offer
ON q.ch_offer_id=tbl_coupan_offer.offer_id
```

Comment: i also want store image in list

Comment: @samirsheikh please check the modification

Comment: given error "#1052 - Column 'category' in field list is ambiguous
"

Comment: sorry, fixed it @samirsheikh

Comment: @ C. Geek error: "#1054 - Unknown column 'q.store_image' in 'field list''

Comment: check again @samirsheikh

Answer (score 7):

Remove `offer_id` from the `select`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT category
FROM tbl_coupon_offer;
```

If you want one `offer_id`, then use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT category, MAX(offer_id)
FROM tbl_coupon_offer
GROUP BY category;
```

Comment: just change the table spelling coupon to coupan

Comment: @Gordon Linoff , when i used 3rd column getting error.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT category , MAX(`offer_id`) , store_image 
FROM  `tbl_coupan_offer` 
GROUP BY `category`
```

If multiple data coming then just add DISTINCT after **SELECT**

Answer (score -2):

Check your database engine type. It is "InnoDB" or not. If your database and table both existed and if you find this error #1146 Table xxx doesn't exist. Then read more about database engine.

If all is right, then query of Gordon is right.

```
SELECT `category`, `offer_id`, `store_image`
FROM `tbl_coupon_offer`
GROUP BY `category`
```

Comment: Amit, I also want store_image column in list

Comment: then add `store_image` in query. I just updated query. check it.