# How to use rank to get rid of duplicate id?

Tags: sql, distinct, ranking, distinct-values, ranking-functions

I have the following two tables:

```
id  | age  | sex  | key  | sport
293   22     m      a     soccer
987   25     f      b     track
501   27     m      c     swimming 
293   22     m      a     soccer
098   31     f      d     soccer
501   27     m      c     swimming
501   27     m      c     swimming
...

key | name 
a     ed
b     meg
c     ben 
a     ed
d     jenny
c     ben
c     ben
....
```

I dont want any duplicate rows of ID.
I want something like this:

```
id  | Name | age  | sex  | key  | sport
293   ed      22     m      a     soccer
987   meg     25     f      b     track
501   ben     27     m      c     swimming 
098   jen     31     f      d     soccer
```

I wrote a query but it doesn't remove the duplicate rows of ID.
I tried doing distinct and group by method too and it still wouldn't remove duplicate IDs.

I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tb1.id, tb1.age, tb2.name, tb1.sport
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN tb2 ON tb1.key = tb2.key
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried distinct and group by methods but still gives me duplicates.

Comment: Your query should work for this sample data. Your data - or query - is probably not exactly as shown here.

Comment: I suppose you could potentially have an issue with whitespace or trailing spaces?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT tb1.id, tb1.age, tb2.name, tb1.sport
FROM table1

This clause will select distinct combinations of these 4 columns and not only distinct ids.

From the above tables:
it will consider the below two rows as distinct:-

```
   a   22   ed   soccer
   a   22   ed  (if any other sport ed plays)
```

I found a similar post which might be helpful for you:
[SELECT DISTINCT on one column, with multiple columns in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48060383/select-distinct-on-one-column-with-multiple-columns-in-mysql)

Comment: How would I be able to use it to get all the columns based on distinct ID then? I tried looking at that link and it didn't help

Comment: Check out this link if it helps-                                                                                             https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937206/sql-query-multiple-columns-using-distinct-on-one-column-only

Answer (score 0):

The reason of duplicate ids that the rows in your second table is also duplicate.
So you distinct only on second table, like this

```
SELECT tb1.id, tb1.age, tb2.name, tb1.sport
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT key, name FROM tb2) AS t2 ON tb1.key = t2.key
```